# Increment through list and find max value for a range of slices

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a problem in which I need to find the max values of a range of slices.

Ex: I have a list of 5,000 ints, and want to find the maximum mean for each slice from 1 to 3600 elements.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
power_vals = # some list / array of ints
max_vals = []
for i in range(1, 3600):
    max_vals += [max([statistics.mean(power_vals[ix:ix+i]) for ix in range(len(power_vals)) if ix+i < len(power_vals)])]
```

This works fine but it's really slow (for obvious reasons). I tried to use cython to speed up the process. It's obviously better but still not ideal.

Is there a more time efficient way to do this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are after. In your code, you have defined a loop where you overwrite `max_vals` 3599 times. At the end `max_vals` is just the result of the last iteration -- but you say the code works. Why did you calculate the previous 3598 values? Maybe you can show an example with a smaller set of data including both input and desired results.

Comment: you can start by not giving it a list to max, as it can take an generator expression, that is just removing the [] from both ends

Comment: If you're looking for the largest mean in any slice length 1 through 3600, you can take a shortcut. It will be the slice with length 1 that has the maximum value in the list. So, the code simply is: `max(power_vals)` its index `power_vals.index(max(power_vals))`

Comment: I've made an edit to the code. Sorry, realize that was confusing. What comes out is another list with max values from the original list increasing the range of values considered by 1 each time.

Comment: max_vals should be [max(power_vals), max of power_vals for 2 elements, max of power_vals for 3 elements, etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is to prepend a 0 to the array, and then create a cumulative sum.  At this point, calculating the mean from any point to any other point is two substractions followed by a division.

`mean(x[i:j]) = (cumsum[j] - cumsum[i])/(j - i)`

If you're trying to find the largest mean of, say, length 10, then you can make it even faster by just looking for the largest value of (cumsum[i + 10] - cumsum[i]).  Once you've found that largest value, you can then divide it by 10 to get the mean.